# Get userManager from ASP.NET Identity Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'd like to be able to get the userManager object for Web Forms Identity.

In order to get the userName a non current user, I need to pass in the userManager into

```
string userName = UserManagerExtensions.FindById(userManager, userID).UserName;
```

However, the userManager is not exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection. Comment from Register.aspx.cs:CreateUser_Click
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
string username = UserManagerExtensions.FindById(userManager, userID).UserName;
```